# Not able to perform Click operation for <List Web Element> for selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

@Friends I am at beginners level so guide me,please let me know if below xpath is correct

```
<ol `id ="no_0a_autocomplete_list" class="autocomplete_list" style..">  
<li class="item current_item" onselect="this.text.value ='DELHI (DLI)'; ">  
<li class="item" onselect="enter code herethis.text.value ='DELHI (DLI)'; ">  
<span>(DLI)</span>DELHI</li>
```

Selenium Code

```
WebElement OlElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='no_0a_autocomplete_list']"));   
List<WebElement> Str= OlElement.findElements(By.tagName("/li/span[text()='(DLI)']"));   
for(WebElement testlist : Str)
{ // Perform click//}
```

Comment: And does it work if you test it? We are here to help you for a given problem. There is a specific StackExchange website for code review.

Comment: By the way you could use `By.id("no_0a_autocomplete_list")` to select the `ol` element.

Comment: @LaurentG below is what I performed and it worked...Thanks for assisting

Answer (score 0):

```
ListWebElement examples = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@id='no_0a_autocomplete_list']/li"));

for (WebElement option: examples) 
{ 
    if ("value".equals(option.getText())) 
    {
         option.click();
         break;
    }       
}
```